# Using className() in a superclass to get the name of a subclass in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have a subclass of `Object` in Realm called `BrowserCategory`, and `Artist`, `Decade` and `Genre` are subclasses of `BrowserCategory`.

Right now each subclass of `BrowserCategory` has this `LinkingObject` property `songs`:

```
let songs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Song.self, property: "decade")
```

(for the `Decade` subclass, for example)

I'd like to write this in the `BrowserCategory` base class so I've tried this:

```
var songs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Song.self, property: className().lowercased())
```

However this returns the base class name and not the subclass name, giving the following error:

```
- Property 'Song.browsercategory' declared as origin of linking objects property 'Decade.songs' does not exist
```

Is there a way to do this the way I want to?

Comment: `type(of:self)`? Might be useful here to look at my online book, which has a section on the topic of how to refer to a type: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_reference

Comment: Thanks @matt but that actually does the same thing (though the string output is slightly different) - it gets the type of the superclass instead of the subclass.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how these classes are related and where you're saying this code. `type(of:)` is polymorphic, as the link explains.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `type(of:self)`, which is polymorphic, as this demonstration illustrates:

```
class BrowserCategory {
    func className() -> String {
        return String(describing:type(of:self))
    }
}
class Artist : BrowserCategory {}
class Decade : BrowserCategory {}
class Genre : BrowserCategory {}

let a = Artist()
a.className() // "Artist"
```

I should caution you, however, that to ask for a class's name as a string is a very odd thing to do. It is more usual to work with a class type as a type.

Comment: Thanks. As I believe i said in my post, I need the class name as a string for Realm's `LinkingObjects` property. I've tried inserting your function above and writing `var songs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Song.self, property: typeName().lowercased())` but I get "cannot use instance member within property initializer...before self is available." Realm provides the `className` property, but as I've shown, using it in the superclass definition of `songs` doesn't pass to the subclasses. And trying `self.className` gives `Value of type (NSObject->()->BrowserCategory has no member className`

Comment: I know nothing about Realm or the `className` method, or what `typeName` is, or what `LinkingObjects` is, etc. etc. I simply demonstrated some code that does what you seemed to say you wanted.